# How do i imbed a video player in my Windows form using SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, video, sharpdevelop

Does anyone know where I could get info on how to imbed a video player into my Windows Form using SharpDevelop? I cannot find any resources or documentation which would guide me although I have found plenty for VisualStudio, but i don't use it.

Comment: The most reliable way to do this is to embed a webbrowser control with a HTML5 video in it.

Comment: @EugenRieck....thnx :) could you give me a brief step thru, pls?